# Split nested parameters using regex

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, split

Can anyone help with a regex method (or other) to split this string

```
string text = "Item -> \"Elephant\", Branches -> 10, Color -> RGB[1, 0, 1], Style -> {Font -> \"Courier New\", Size -> 7}, Display -> True";
```

to obtain

```
List<string> directives = new List<string>();
```

containing the following five strings?

```
"Item -> \"Elephant\""
"Branches -> 10"
"Color -> RGB[1, 0, 1]"
"Style -> {Font -> \"Courier New\", Size -> 7}"
"Display -> True"
```

Comment: You can implode your string based on `,`

Comment: Problem is that there are commas within the values, it makes the logic so much more difficult, because what's the condition for when to split on comma and when shouldn't you split on comma? You likely need to introduce some escape based logic

Comment: @Shafizadeh Won't that split up the RGB and Style directives?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Yes, that's the problem.

Comment: [`(\w+)\s+->\s+({[^{}]*}|(?:.*?)(?=, \w+\s+->|$))`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5cw%2b)%5cs%2b-%3e%5cs%2b(%7b%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%7d%7c(%3f%3a.*%3f)(%3f%3d%2c+%5cw%2b%5cs%2b-%3e%7c%24))&i=Item+-%3e+%22Elephant%22%2c+Branches+-%3e+10%2c+Color+-%3e+RGB%5b1%2c+0%2c+1%5d%2c+Style+-%3e+%7bFont+-%3e+%22Courier+New%22%2c+Size+-%3e+7%7d%2c+Display+-%3e+True).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**Option 1:**

`([^,]+{[^}]+})|([^,]+\[[^\]]+\])|([^,]+)`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fX9dD4/1)

Input:

```
Item -> \"Elephant\", Branches -> 10, Color -> RGB[1, 0, 1], Style -> {Font -> \"Courier New\", Size -> 7}, Display -> True
```

Output:

```
MATCH 1
3.  [0-20]  `Item -> \"Elephant\"`
MATCH 2
3.  [21-36] ` Branches -> 10`
MATCH 3
2.  [37-59] ` Color -> RGB[1, 0, 1]`
MATCH 4
1.  [60-106]    ` Style -> {Font -> \"Courier New\", Size -> 7}`
MATCH 5
3.  [107-123]   ` Display -> True`
```

Explanation:

`([^,]+{[^}]+})` captures `Any -> {Any}`
`([^,]+\[[^\]]+\])` captures `Any -> [Any]`
`([^,]+)` captures others except `,`

**Option 2:**

```
,\s*(?![^{]+}|[^\[]+\])
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yC6iE2/1)

Output:

```
Item -> \"Elephant\"
Branches -> 10
Color -> RGB[1, 0, 1]
Style -> {Font -> \"Courier New\", Size -> 7}
Display -> True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to split:

```
,\s*(?=\s*[^,]+-)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xH8kK5/4)

Comment: Wow, looks promising...  except it split the Style directive.  Think I need to add something for the curly braces.

Comment: Yeah.. it will be difficult to consider where to split with that.. it might need changing the string with escape characters